# A Work-Around For AWS Cognito Custom Attributes? Using JavaScript With Angular

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

At this time custom attributes are poorly setup by AWS.  For example, you can't find the custom field you entered in the Console in user objects returned by various JS SDK api's unless you have a value in it. (I have checked the read / write boxes for the custom attributes.)  To do that you have to enter the value with the CLI, which is unworkable for real apps that are meant for users to add data with a GUI.

Also, the adminCreateUser api doc states this:
"For custom attributes, you must prepend the custom: prefix to the attribute name."

So apparently you are supposed to be able to add a custom field on creation but good luck with that.  At least in JavaScript I haven't found a way for it to accept custom:whatever without crashing the app build.  I'm not able to find any way to use these fields with any api because custom: is rejected by JS.

Has anyone found a work-around / hack to fix this problem?

This doesn't work in the adminCreateUser api with custom: but it is fine with the others:

```
const createUserParams = {
          UserPoolId: this.cognitoUserPoolID,
          Username: enteredData.user_name,
          DesiredDeliveryMediums: ['EMAIL'],
          ForceAliasCreation: false,
          MessageAction: 'SUPPRESS',
          UserAttributes: [
            {
              Name: 'custom:user_id',
              Value: enteredData.custom:user_id
            },
            {
              Name: 'given_name',
              Value: enteredData.given_name
            },  ...
```

Calling listUsers api gives an error message in the console.

```
Error in getCognitoUsers:  Error: One or more requested attributes do not exist.
```

The listUsers api requires these params:

```
return new Observable(observer => {
      const listUsersParams = {
        AttributesToGet: [
          'custom:user_id',
          'given_name',
          'family_name',
          'locale',
          'email',
        ],
        // Filter: '',
        UserPoolId: this.cognitoApisService.cognitoUserPoolID
      };

      const cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new CognitoIdentityServiceProvider(AWSconfig);

      cognitoidentityserviceprovider.listUsers(listUsersParams, function (err, userData) {
```

Comment: Your code is not correct: `Value: enteredData.custom:user_id`.

Comment: Your suggestion looks exactly like what I have.  By the way, all the standard attributes work fine.  The " : " is the problem.  JS doesn't like it.

Comment: That is because JavaScript variables do not have `:` in the name. I showed you the line with the problem. You are building the value incorrectly.

Comment: You have the same property as I do.  Maybe I'm blind today but your suggestion looks exactly like mine.  You have a colon, I have a colon in the same place, and all the docs say to put it there.  I'm puzzled.

Comment: I am showing you the line that has the problem not the solution. My line is exactly the same because it is your line that I am showing you that is broken. Now you know what to fix.

Comment: This post is about that line.  I already knew what to fix.  I can't figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with this line: `Value: enteredData.custom:user_id`. The issue is that you are trying to change the variable name with the string `custom:`. Instead you add `custom:` to the Name value.

```
{
    Name: 'custom:user_id',
    Value: enteredData.user_id
},
```

Comment: Thank you.  That makes sense.  I had the wrong mental map of how this may work.  However ```AttributesToGet: [
          'custom:user_id',``` is throwing errors.  See my last section of code above.  I may have entered the user_id into Cognito but I can't see it in the returned object yet.  That line is also a problem.

Comment: The error is ```Error: One or more requested attributes do not exist.```  custom:user_id is the only requested attribute causing this error.

Answer (score 1):

John Hanley solved part of the problem with appending custom: to a property name.  I wasn't able to find a solution to JavaScript rejecting `AttributesToGet: [ 'custom:user_id'` so since that isn't required I deleted `AttributesToGet` in my request params and all attributes are returned in the response object.

Since JavaScript really doesn't like a colon in an object property I've created this work-around:

`let userID = data['custom:user_id'];`

If iterating through an array this is helpful:

`const user_id = usersArray[i]['custom:user_id'];`

To fix the response object to access the data for say a data table just add the new field and value to the object.

`usersArray[i].user_id = usersArray[i]['custom:user_id'];`

After this just access the property in dot notation.